# Download a PDF as a download popup rather than the inbuilt browser PDF viewer

Tags: marketing-cloud, pdf, ssjs, cloudpage

I'm trying to get a PDF to download via a cloud page, so when the user accesses the page it will show them a popup to download a PDF from a URL.

I have the code that achieves this but my PDF that is downloaded just includes blank white pages rather than the content.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

The function I'm using is

```
var DownloadPDF = function(url, filename)
{   
    HTTPHeader.SetValue("Content-Type","application/pdf");
    HTTPHeader.SetValue("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="'+filename+'"');
    Write(HTTP.Get(url).Content);
}
```

Comment: It might be easier to host the PDF inside of Content Builder and then use the corresponding URL as the 'link' the user clicks on.  This will also let them view the PDF via the browser as well as provide the option to download it.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use JavaScript to download a PDF file from a CloudPage. I would avoid implementing as a pop-up, as most browsers block pop-up windows by default.

Here's an example:

```js
%%[
var @pdfDownloadUrl
set @pdfDownloadUrl = 'https://url-to-pdf-file.com/file.pdf'
]%%
<script>
  window.location.href = '%%=v(@pdfDownloadUrl)=%%';
</script>
```

When the page loads, the PDF file will download to the default 'download directory' used by the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the HttpHeader as `application/octet-stream`

Comment: Unfortunately not, I had already tried with octet-stream and it performed the same as using the PDF mime type

Answer (score 0):

You can have your PDF as a page and get its content without actually loading the page in Apex.

```
public Blob downloadPDF(){

    ApexPages.PageReference refPage = Page.MyPDFPage;
    refPage.getParameters().put( 'id', myrecordIdVariable );
    refPage.setRedirect( false );
    Blob pdfValue = refPage.getContentAsPDF();

    return pdfValue;
}
```

You can then pull in this to build your file.

Comment: This is for Marketing Cloud, not Apex.